# teams webhook - AdaptiveCard - Help to collapse a long custom teams message

Tags: microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

Usecase - Send test results as a custom message to teams. Using [test-results-reporter](https://test-results-reporter.github.io/targets/teams.html)
Issue - Lot of test scenarios, results in long message in teams. Need help/config to collapse the long message with "See more" option.

```
"$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
```

I have tried looking into - [Microsoft teams developer documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/mstdd-landing)  didn't find any config which I can add to the payload

Comment: Are you sending the adaptive card with messages to MS Teams using incoming webhook? Could you please share the JSON ?

Comment: Could you please share the above asked details?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/AdaptiveCards/issues/4583

Comment: Thanks, @Fawkes - It answers my question. "Adaptive card has never supported see-more, this is by design."